# make: The scope of SECONDEXPANSION

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

What is the scope of secondary expansion in a makefile?

If i type:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
```

Where does this change stop? Does it apply to the all targets from that point onward? or only up until the next target?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It applies to all targets from then on. From [the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion):

```
...All the prerequisites of the targets defined after the special target are expanded a second time.
```

And if you doubt the documentation, you can *try it.* Modifying an examples from the docs:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
main_OBJS := main.o try.o test.o
lib_OBJS := lib.o api.o

main: $$($$@_OBJS)
    @echo prerequisites are $^

lib: $$($$@_OBJS)
    @echo prerequisites are $^
```